# how to invoke bundler commands from within a Serverspec/RSpec test

Tags: ruby, serverspec

I have a project to create a template ruby project.

I am using serverspec and want to verify the behaviour of the template.

However, using `` command(`rake -T`) `` fails.  If I execute the command manually, it works as expected.

Debugging, when the test is running in Serverspec, it finds the wrong `Gemfile` - it is using the Gemfile from my project (`.`), not the generated directory (`target/sample_project`).

How can I invoke `rake` or `bundler` commands withing a Serverspec/Rspec test?

sample code:

```
require "spec_helper"
require 'serverspec'
require 'fileutils'

set :backend, :exec
set :login_shell, true

describe "Generated Template" do
  output_dir='target'
  project_dir="#{output_dir}/sample_project"

  # Hooks omitted to create the sample_project 
  # and change working directory to `project_dir`

  describe command('rake -T') do
    its(:stdout) { should include "rake serverspec:localhost" }
    its(:stdout) { should include "rake serverspec:my_app" }
  end
end
```

Comment: could you add `cd target/sample_project && rake && cd -` to the command?

Comment: I've tried that.  I have actually added an around hook, to change the current directory: `around(:example) do Dir.chdir(project_dir) end`.  This works as expected - I have another example to check that the working directory is as expected.

Comment: The hook might not work because a new child process will be started which may not have the same current working directory as the parent process. Did you try to put the `cd` inside the command so it is executed in the context of the child process?

Comment: Yes.  I've also confirmed that the hook is working as expected using `pwd && rake`.  I've set `set :shell, '/bin/bash'` which is getting me further, but I'm getting `Warning: PATH set to RVM ruby but GEM_HOME and/or GEM_PATH not set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler has provision for running external shell commands documented here: http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Running bundler/rake tasks is possible using rspec using `Bundler.with_clean_env`, instead of Serverspec.

```
require 'bundler'
require 'rspec'
RSpec.describe "Generated Template" do

  output_dir='target'
  project_dir="#{output_dir}/sample_project"

  around(:example) do |example|
    #Change context, so we are in the generated project directory
    orig_dir=Dir.pwd

    Dir.chdir(project_dir)
    example.run
    Dir.chdir(orig_dir)

  end

  around(:example) do |example|
    Bundler.with_clean_env do
      example.run
    end
  end

  it "should include localhost" do
    expect(`rake -T 2>&1`).to include "rake serverspec:localhost"
  end
end
```